# Change app settings inside Express.js request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it good practice to change app settings inside request Express.js handler?

```
app.set('title', 'My Site')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.set('title', 'My Site')

app.get('/somehow', function (req, res) {
  req.app.set('title', 'New title')
  res.send('hello world')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: `app` settings are essentially global to the server so it would be a very rare case where it makes sense to change a global server setting in one particular request handler serving one particular client because it can affect all future requests from all future clients.  I could imagine perhaps some administrative control that might do that, but not normal client requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 its exactly what I need. Some global server setting changed with http request.

Comment: Unless you're sending raw data like JSON, it would be preferable to just set a title in HTML, or if you want it to be dynamic with a template like pug or ejs.

Comment: What is the actual application for this?  Is it really just setting a title or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good practice to change app settings inside request Express.js handler?

It can be used just fine if what you're intending to do is to change a global server setting that could affect all future requests from all future clients.  Typically, this would be done under some sort of administrative authentication  (not by any random client) or just be some type of server metric you're accumulating.

It would not be the appropriate way of affecting one particular response (because it's affect is persistent and affects all future requests).  For that, you should modify that one response locally, either manually or by using an HTML template.  For passing data to templates, you can pass it directly or set it in `res.locals` and the template can render the page using that data.

---

If this is for business logic, then you generally do not want to make business logic dependent upon the Express framework as there's really no reason to make one dependent upon the other.  Instead, you can implement a stand-alone module for your business logic that keeps track of its own state and exports an interface for getting/setting/implementing the business logic.  It can then store state as module-level variables or in a database or in whatever is most appropriate.

Make this business logic a stand-alone module also makes it independently testable without Express, usable in other apps, simpler to debug, etc...

Comment: I need exactly global state change in this particular case. My example with title does not reflect business logic. My app should track some number of available items, and each request should decrement it.

Comment: @Molfar - Usually, business logic would not be kept on the `app` object, but in a module that uses a module-level variable or data structure and then exports methods for modifying the state.

Comment: @Molfar - This is because business logic has no reason to be dependent upon Express.  It can stand-alone in its own module with its own interface.  In fact, the business logic should continue to work just fine without rewriting it if you switched to a different web framework.